# Case insensitive comparison in Contains under nUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, contains, assert

I'm trying to assert that a list contains a certain string. Since I'd need the condition to be evaluated case insensitively, I used a workaround (something along [this blog post](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-make-string-contains-case-insensitive/)).

However, I'd like to know why there seems not to be a way to make the *Assert.Contains* method perform the comparison without regard of case sensitivity. Or is there a way to do that? (When I googled it, I only got hits on constraints for the *Assert.That* method on the official page for nUnit.)

Comment: Are you using nUnit? If so, it contains a `StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase` method you could use here. Alternatively, you could `ToUpper()` both strings in your comparison as another bandaid.

Comment: @aevitas Hmm... That breaks the *Assert.SomeSome* looks... But if that's the recommended way to do that, then so be it. As to my question-in-depth: any idea why there's no *Contains* with an extra parameter to comparison control?

Comment: I have no clue, there may be an actual reason for it, but it could just as well be overlooked. If you really want to stick to the `Assert.Some` looks, you could use `Assert.IsTrue(string.Equals(left, right, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Comment: @aevitas That's what I'm doing already, hehe. I was just worry that there was a reason I didn't know about that would comer to bite me in the sitting device. Put in your thoughts as a reply so I can accept the answer if nobody else outshines you, please.

Comment: I have now, but you don't have to accept it if it doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: @aevitas It does to 99%. The rest, I took the liberty to add to it. And woosh! Now, you're 10 points more trusted by SO. Congrats!   :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no way to specify *ignoreCase* in the `Assert.Contains`. Whether it's something that is overlooked or intended I do not know. You can, however, use

```csharp
StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase(left, right);
```

in your unit tests to achieve the same results.

Alternatively, if you wish to stick with the `Assert.Foo()` "theme", you could do something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(string.Equals(left, right, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

or, since `Contains` treats arrays:

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Any(element => element.ToUpper() == "VILTERSTEN"));
```

where you call `ToUpper()` on both the left and right string operands, which effectively makes the comparison ignore case as well. `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is to ensure some corner cases (read: Turkish) of cultures do not cause unexpected results. If you are interested in reading up on that, have a look at [the Turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: +1 for the turkey. I though you meant the bird, hehe. Very interesting article.

Answer (score 20):

In NUnit 3, the following syntax can be used:

```cs
Assert.That(new[] {"red", "green", "blue"}, Does.Contain("RED").IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This is working fine, is readable, following framework mechanics and in my opinion it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

nUnit does provide that and it reads:

```
Assert.That("red,green,blue".Split(','), Contains.Item("RED").IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Using 3.10 and .IgnoreCore is not supported anymore.  Better to use the answer below with nunit 3.